# Homebrew Software Update Issue

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

[Click here to see terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4tBY.png)

Whenever I run the command "brew doctor" I get a response stating that I need to update Homebrew. When I then proceed to update Homebrew with "brew update" I get a response stating that Homebrew is already up to date. Is this something I should be concerned about? Is there a way to fix this? I attached a screenshot of my terminal output for clarification. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Had a similar issue today. Manually updating by `cd /usr/local && git pull origin master` solved the problem for me.

Comment: That worked for me too. Want to add it as an official answer? I’ll upvote.

Comment: Somehow my github link vanished. Whoever supported the removal: Please don't do that... :) The official recommendations how to takle this can be found here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core#update-bug

Comment: @RobinWhittleton, this is just a temporary glitch. I think it's helpful for others to find link to the solution. But it will not be of long term relevance - So I am not planning to submit an answer. You can do so however if you want.

Comment: Had a similar problem -- 'brew update' has been reporting "Already up-to-date" for many days running, which I did not believe to be true.  'brew doctor' reported no problems.  Ran `git pull origin master` followed by 'brew update', and brew reported many packages were out of date.